# python if (X not in Y) or (Z not in Y) condition unexpected result

Tags: python, if-statement, in-operator

There is a list of file names, like:

```
files = ["f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f1.txt", "f3.pdf"]
```

and I want to find those files that have a "txt" or "pdf" equivalent with the same name and remove them from the list. so the desired output is **`f2 f4 f1.txt f3.pdf`**
I tried this:

```
for f in files: 
     if f+".txt" not in files or f+".pdf" not in files: 
         print(f)
```

output: `f1 f2 f3 f4 f1.txt f3.pdf` which is wrong.

I also tried with parenthesizes around each condition and `not f+".txt" in files` but no luck.
By removing both or one of "not"s, the output is as expected:

```
for f in files: 
     if f+".txt" in files or f+".pdf" in files: 
         print(f)
```

output: `f1 f3`
To get the desired output, I can use a pass statement in if block and print(f) in an else block.
But the question is "why does not the first code work?" I searched a little bit before posting but they weren't exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: what is your desired outcome?

Comment: You want `and`, not `or`. `f` can't be both `.txt` and `.pdf`, so one of the condition halves will always be true.

Comment: You can create a modified list with `[file for file in files if f'{file}.txt' not in files and f'{file}.pdf' not in files]` - but I have the feeling there should be a better way.

Comment: @YashMakan this: f2 f4 f1.txt f3.pdf

Comment: @Carcigenicate Your are so right, the way I was thinking about it was all wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @AliAfif It's a very common mistake. I find when dealing with difficult conditions, it helps to say the condition out loud to help reason about it (like, actually speaking it out loud). It also helps to remove the variables from the condition and replace them with actual data so the condition is less abstract.

Comment: change the ```or``` to ```and```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
files = ["f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f1.txt", "f3.pdf"]
for f in files: 
     if f+".txt" not in files and f+".pdf" not in files:
         print(f)
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_